# Umbrella term for treasury bills, notes and bonds

Tags: terminology, finance

I am using interest rate data for all these treasury securities. Because bills, notes and bonds all are used for a certain maturity interval (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Treasury_security#Directly_issued_by_the_United_States_government). I would like to know if one of the three words can be used as an umbrella term for them. 
Should I just use "treasuries" or should I go for the slightly longer "treasury securities"? Additionally, I would like to know if it should be capitalized in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a domain-specific usage (that might be better addressed on SE [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) or [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: I thought about https://quant.stackexchange.com/, but that's rather technical and I am interested in the usage of these terms in an academic paper.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: isn't that what the `terminology` tag is for, domain-specific lingo?

Comment: @TRomano: First, the existence of any given tag needn't imply that all questions to which that tag might seem "applicable" must be definition be "On Topic". Second, the exact *scope* of that tag is open to interpretation. And third, I have VTCd many questions citing "domain-specific usage" over the years - which still seems a perfectly reasonable position to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can refer to them as US Treasury **[securities](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/auctfund/work/auctime/auctime_securitiestable.htm)**.

Answer (score 0):

**Treasuries**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205377?rskey=fQf3RN&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> c. plural. Treasury bills.

As in:

*Daily Tel. 8 Oct.    This week's ‘hot’ **Treasuries** offered at ¾ p.c. found buyers.*